# Docker remove multiple images and keep last two

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins

what i am trying to do is remove all images and only keep last two images of every build. i have almost achieved this but i am getting some docker rmi error although the script successfully removed images which i don't need. also if there is a way to make it more precise or clean please happy get help.

docker images

```
REPOSITORY                         TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api01      prod-20210402-43    fd01be2be633        54 minutes ago      201 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api01      qa-20210401-5       6783fc21395f        23 hours ago        217 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api02      qa-20210401-33      241107762154        23 hours ago        232 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api02      prod-20210331-19      51a8f604b1bc        2 days ago          201 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api02      qa-20210329-32      28a750d97d74        3 days ago          232 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api02      prod-20210325-5       3d1004b7b97f        8 days ago          233 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api02      prod-20210325-18      9d6c34c0623b        8 days ago          201 MB
Mystg.azurecr.io/repo/api02      qa-20210324-43      7a3d071b91b0        8 days ago          222 MB
```

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
pqimage=$(<images.txt)

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
log_path="`pwd`"
filename=docker_cleanup_$timestamp.log
log=$log_path/$filename

docker_space_before(){
CURRENTSPACE=`docker system df`
echo "Current Docker Space:"
echo $CURRENTSPACE >> $log
}

for PRIMAGES in ${pqimage}; do
docker images | grep  "M*/$PRIMAGES" | grep "prod-2021*" | tail -n +3 >> $log
sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep  "M*/$PRIMAGES" | grep "prod-2021*" | tail -n +3)
done

for QAIMAGES in ${pqimage}; do
docker images | grep  "M*/$QAIMAGES" | grep "qa-2021*" | tail -n +3 >> $log
sudo docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep  "M*/$QAIMAGES" | grep "qa-2021*" | tail -n +3)
done
```

Error

````
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).```
````

Comment: Try pasting your script at http://shellcheck.net

Comment: Also I suggest using an array for `pqimage`  e.g. `mapfile -t pqimage < image.txt` rather than your previous use of command substitution.

Comment: Try without the `for` loop. Each `docker rmi` is already trying to remove all images.

Comment: i am down to 3 loop Errors.
` "docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images
"docker rmi" requires at least 1 argument(s).
See 'docker rmi --help'.

Usage:  docker rmi [OPTIONS] IMAGE [IMAGE...]

Remove one or more images `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if there are any images to remove before removing it. Also, do not run `docker images` twice... just use variables.

```
for PRIMAGES in $pqimage; do
    tmp=$(docker images | grep  "M*/$PRIMAGES" | grep "prod-2021*" | tail -n +3)
    echo "$tmp" >> "$log"
    if [[ -n "$tmp" ]]; then
       sudo docker rmi -f $tmp
    fi
done
```

Check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net

Do not use backticks `. Use $(...) instead.

Quote variable expansions.

Indent function body.

Do not use uppercase variables for internal variables. Prefer lower case variables in your scripts.

Cache the result of `docker images`. It's not like it changes each loop...

I think I would do something along:

```
# One could use `tee`, but I think it's clearer with one temporary variable.
tmp=$(docker images | grep -f <(printf "M*/%s\n" $pqimage))
{
   <<<"$tmp" grep "prod-2021*" | tail -n +3 | tee >(cat >>"$log")
   <<<"$tmp" grep "qa-2021*"   | tail -n +3 | tee >(cat >>"$log")
} | xargs -d'\n' -r sudo docker rmi -f
```

Or even you could use a single `awk` to just do parsing in one stage.

Comment: thanks for the improvement in my script i'll try today and let you know where i am